# Как можно перевернуть число в C++?

Tags: c++

Для наглядности: на вход программе даётся число, к примеру **1234**. Нужно сделать так, чтобы на выходе вывелось число **4321**. Как это можно реализовать в C++? Нужно, чтобы на выходе перевёрнутая переменная была типа **int**.

Буду признателен всем ответам.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int n = 4321;
int m = 0;
while(n)
{
    m = m*10+n%10;
    n /= 10;
}
cout << m << endl;
```